# How to select rows containing the smallest value above k?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say I have the following Pandas DataFrame :

```
  |-----+-----+------+-----|
  |     | ... |    I | ... |
  |-----+-----+------+-----|
  |   0 | ... |   20 | ... |
  |   1 | ... |   20 | ... |
  |   2 | ... |   50 | ... |
  |   3 | ... |   50 | ... |
  |   4 | ... |  100 | ... |
  |   5 | ... |  100 | ... |
  |   6 | ... |  250 | ... |
  |   7 | ... |  250 | ... |
  |   8 | ... |  500 | ... |
  |   9 | ... |  500 | ... |
  |  10 | ... | 1000 | ... |
  |  11 | ... | 1000 | ... |
  | ... | ... |  ... | ... |
  |-----+-----+------+-----|
```

I'd like to retrieve the rows that have a value equal to the first value higher than `k` in column `I`.

For `k=347` it would be :

```
  |-----+-----+------+-----|
  |     | ... |    I | ... |
  |-----+-----+------+-----|
  |   8 | ... |  500 | ... |
  |   9 | ... |  500 | ... |
  |-----+-----+------+-----|
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['I']>=k]`

Comment: `df[df['I"] ==df.loc[df['I']>k,'I'].min()]`

Comment: Thank you @QuangHoang it works well. `df[df['I']` should be written instead of `df[df['I"]`